# Difference between OperationTimeout and SendTimeout in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

After quite a bit of searching, I could not find the answer to this question.

What is exact difference between [`OperationTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icontextchannel.operationtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SendTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? I read `OperationTimeout` is a subset of `SendTimeout` and `SendTimeout` includes writing message in the channel. If you give more details that would be great.

My second question is I have client call to a service where I just want to set timeout between soon after request sent to the server and soon after received reply from the server. How to set this timeout?

Comment: This looks also helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2010/03/06/timeouts-in-wcf-and-their-default-values.aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd like to propose reading [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/) from Brian McNamara over on the MSFT forums:

> Brief summary of binding timeout
>   knobs...
>
> Client side:
>
> - SendTimeout is used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which
>     governs the whole interaction for
>     sending a message (including receiving
>     a reply message in a request-reply
>     case).  This timeout also applies when
>     sending reply messages from a
>     CallbackContract method.
> - OpenTimeout and CloseTimeout are used when opening and closing channels
>     (when no explicit timeout value is
>     passed).
> - ReceiveTimeout is not used.
>
> Server side:
>
> - Send, Open, and Close Timeout same as on client (for Callbacks).
> - ReceiveTimeout is used by ServiceFramework layer to initialize
>     the session-idle timeout.

Comment: Many thanks - new thing that I learned today. Brian's comment can also be verified now that BCL is open source. See here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/ServiceChannel.cs,17fea1adf191b5b7

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question and WCF has reached its end of life - nevertheless I stumbled upon this exact problem.

The answer which Vincent quoted from Brian McNamara is correct (`SendTimeout` is used to initialize the `OperationTimeout`). It is just not complete.

The `SendTimeout` also covers the time which is used for sending (the write operation itself) the data! [See the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

This really makes a difference if you increase the `OperationTimeout` for certain heavy services. But do not increase the `SendTimeout` on the binding (for all services!) and a whole lot of data has to be transmitted via a poor line. That was the problem I ran into...