# WCF. Timeout exceptions on client. sendTimeout. Load test showing weird numbers. Why?

Tags: .net, wcf

**Service**

I have WCF service under high load. Response time is averaging ~60 ms.
Service uses mostly default configuration, except of maxConcurrentCalls="5000", endpoint with basicHttpBinding is exposed.

**Client**

Another service (further "client") is consuming this one. Infrequently (like 0.5%) there are TimeoutExceptions (*). sendTimeout on client is set to "00:00:05".

**Load Test**

I can reproduce same with VS Load Testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    using (var client = new SomeServiceClient())
    {
        // some randomization to make request more realistic
        var response = client.GetSomething(request);
    }
}
```

**Timeouts disappear when:**

1. I increase sendTimeout.
2. I create one channel and reuse it during
   whole load testing.

**Now weird stuff:**

Load test (even when there are timeouts) shows test time averaging 0.06, and at maximum taking 0.2 second, which is by far lower than 5 seconds.
This also happens in production (logs say so), but no customer impact identified so far.

**Question**

*Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong?*

Alternatively: what would you suggest for this scenario in terms on WCF configuration/instancing/etc?

As of scalability all this stuff is already running on many hosts: client on 4 hosts, service as well on 4 hosts. Would increase in number of clients help here?

---

(*) When I refer to TimeoutExceptions I always mean client side exceptions.

System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:05. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'http://someservice.intranet/99.99/someendpoint.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:05. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

---

*Any WCF gurus willing to help?*

Comment: 1. There are few other timeouts, in most cases you need to modify recieveTimeout

Comment: 2. You need turn on full tracing. In SvcTraceViewer.exe you will be able to see nice diagram of what is going on and where lag is.

Comment: @Mike Chaliy, I'm sure it has something to do with sendTimeout, as increasing it helps. Also this says that recieveTimeout is not used on client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303116/difference-between-operation-timeout-and-sendtimeout-in-wcf (don't know if I can believe in this)

Comment: @MikeChaliy as of tracing. I didn't think about it before. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: When you removed this one aspect "one channel and reuse it" you eliminated going to the network stack and creating a new connection for each call. Same logic holds true with pure DB connections, many times the most costly event is establishing the connection. Re-use an established connection wherever possible.