# WCF Binding Timeouts for Send,Receive,Open,Close not being recognized

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding

I am not quite sure if I am testing these correctly, but I am trying to determine the impact of one of the Timeouts for (Close,Receive,Send,Open) for the binding on the service.

I am programatically setting the values because I prefer it over configuration based so please dont recommend me putting it back in the config file.

To test the extreme, I am attempting to set the  Timeout to 1 second so that it should hit no matter what.

I am not sure however that this is the case

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        ServiceThrottlingBehavior behavior = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
        behavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1000;
        behavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = 1000;
        behavior.MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000;
        serviceDescription.Behaviors.Add(behavior);


        foreach (var endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
        {
            var binding = endpoint.Binding;
            binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            endpoint.Binding = binding;
        }

        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cd in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {

            foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
            {
                if (!ed.IsSystemEndpoint)
                {
                    ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new MyProvider(serviceDescription.ServiceType)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tracing enabled as well and have been trying to monitor it to see if anything has changed, but  nothing has caught my eye.

Comment: Take a look at this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5310933/745969

Comment: this link only tells me what each of the timeout types are, but is not helpful at all in why they are not actually timing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read this note in the MSDN API documentation for `ApplyDispatchBehavior`?

> All of the IServiceBehavior methods pass
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription and
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase objects as a parameters. The
>   ServiceDescription parameter is for examination and insertion of
>   customizations only; if you otherwise modify these objects the
>   execution behavior is undefined.

The `ServiceDescription` and `Binding` object are not part of the runtime channel stack, but rather are used just to determine how the runtime should be built when the `ServiceHost` is opened and the channel listener first created.

Your service behavior's `ApplyDispatchBehavior` is called during initialisation of the channel listener and runtime channel stack, too late for your changes to the timeout properties of the Binding object itself to have any effect on the channel run time being built.

You may have more luck if you set these properties in `AddBindingParameters` instead, as that method is called earlier in the process of building the runtime but even though that might work, it's still undefined behavior.

Really, though, these properties should be set on the Binding before the `ServiceHost` is opened.