# Is WCF binding SendTimeout only used to initialize channel OperationTimeout?

Tags: wcf, timeout, wcf-binding

Note: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303116/difference-between-operationtimeout-and-sendtimeout-in-wcf), [that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/explaination-of-different-timeout-types?forum=wcf) and [yonder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and it's still not entirely clear if I get this:

The WCF Binding [SendTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as well as the WCF IContextChannel [OperationTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icontextchannel.operationtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both, according to MSDN:

> Gets or sets the time period within which an operation must complete or an exception is thrown. <sub>(If transaction flow is enabled on the binding or the channel, the operation may take longer to execute than the specified timeout. In these circumstances the operation fails due to the expired timeout and the transaction aborts appropriately.)</sub>

And also according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> SendTimeout – **used to initialize the OperationTimeout**, which governs the whole process of sending a message, including receiving a reply message for a request/reply service operation.

So, the `SendTimeout` property of a Binding *is not* used as a real timeout at all, it is **just**(??!) used to initialize the default of (all?) communication Channels' `OperationTimeout`?

Note: I verified that when I set `Binding.SendTimeout` to a non-default value, the channel returned by `ChannelFactory.CreateChannel` (when factory is initialized with the binding) has indeed the same `IContextChannel.OperationTimeout` as the set SendTimeout.

Is there anything more to this, or is the SendTimeout indeed just the initializer value for the OperationTimeout on the channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, all settings on the binding are just for "design time". In run time, they are used initialize the channels which are the effective values.

Comment: Indeed this seems so: "ReceiveTimeout – used by the Service Framework Layer *to initialize* the session-idle timeout". Good observation.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in a one liner:

No it is not (only used to initalize the OperationContext).

It is also used to cover the timeout for the write operation itself. I did also answer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67000004/2243584).