# WCF what is the Timeout difference?

Tags: wcf

I need to find out what is the difference between :-

```
client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 120)
```

And

```
 binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
 binding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
```

(This on the client side)

Basically we are after setting the time from when the service is open (from request) to retrieve (from response)

And not knowing the difference above is given me a lack of confidence

Thanks

**EDIT**

As there are many links and a lot of reading, the answer is

> SendTimeout is used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which governs
>   the whole interaction for sending a message (including receiving a
>   reply message in a request-reply case). This timeout also applies when
>   sending reply messages from a CallbackContract method

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: You might get some additional info from here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/95f21f62-c415-4ffa-b12b-f57529b02816/dynamically-changing-wcf-sendtimeout ) or here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2010/03/06/timeouts-in-wcf-and-their-default-values.aspx) but this is not an area I'm familiar with so it may not be that much use to you.

Comment: Thanks I was looking at these two, gives me more to go on, but would be nice to get an answer if someone does know. Will up vote it for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Which is where? Nothing on MSDN..."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2010/03/06/timeouts-in-wcf-and-their-default-values.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.opentimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Even a google search yields in results :)

[Difference between OperationTimeout and SendTimeout in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303116/difference-between-operationtimeout-and-sendtimeout-in-wcf)

http://final-proj.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/wcf-timeouts.html

essentially the OperationTimeout is just that... the time out value for an operation to complete and come back within the specified timeout value. It's like "it should take you x minutes to make a cup of coffee"... and if you don't then its a timeout. In other words, it is the time taken for an operation to complete.

Comment: Thanks - the best exemption is Difference between OperationTimeout and SendTimeout in WCF link. the others are misleading and don't actually answer my question.

Comment: Not sure I follow? The links give you explainations for each of the properties in your original question. Let me ask - what problems are you facing? :)

Comment: The original question was "what are the differences between" the links don't actually state the differences, expect for the link I stated above, yes, they give good information on timeouts so this would have been best suited for a question such as "what are the numerous timeouts in WCF" but thanks for your research, I can see this helping many people.